# emberjs - nested tables info

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have an irregular table structure I would like to nest (either using actual tables or using div tables). I have a list of 'Parent' classes, each of which has many 'Children' instances, and I want to show them in the same table, with a single set of headers.  I would like the output to be something like this (simplified - I have many more columns to display).

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Parent</th>
    <th>Child</th>
    <th>Remove</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">parent one</td>
    <td>child one</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>child two</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But I can't figure out how to accomplish this in handlebars because of the fact that I need to have a new `<tr>` element around every child *except* for the first one. This is easy enough to figure out in code, but I can't see how to do it cleanly in handlebars. Is it possible or should I write a custom view?

Comment: The only resource that I know to simplify the use of tables in ember is ember-table. http://addepar.github.io/ember-table/. Please give a look, maybe can help.